# Value Error Obtained while creating a new dataframe which contains the min and max of a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below.I need to find the min and max of the column "**Chip_Current[uAmp]**" I used the below code to create a new data frame but obtained an error.

**ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns.**

```
data = [[DEEP_SLEEP_PVT['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].min()], [DEEP_SLEEP_PVT['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].max()]]
df_DS = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['MIN', 'MAX'])
```

DEEP_SLEEP_PVT is my pivot table name

After running the code provided by Jerzel output is coming as expected. Please see below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you you're trying to concatenate two columns in your RHS as if they were a plain old Python list: `data = [[DS['CC'].min()], [DS['CC'].max()]`. But they're Series, so you should use `pd.concat([DS['CC'].min()], [DS['CC'].max()])`. Or the alternatives jezrael suggests.

Comment: It helps your code clarity a lot if you rename your dataframe `ds` and your column 'Chip_Current[uAmp]' -> 'CC'. In Python variable names like 'DEEP_SLEEP_PVT' should always be lower-case (unless they're constants). Column names can be whatever you want, but short makes for nicer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.aggregate.html), output is `Series`, so for one row `DataFrame` convert it to `DataFrame` and transpose:

```
df1 = DEEP_SLEEP_PVT['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].agg(['min','max']).to_frame().T
```

If need minimal and maximal per some another column/level like `Device_ID` use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2 = DEEP_SLEEP_PVT.groupby('Device_ID')['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].agg(['min','max'])
```

Or by multiple columns/levels:

```
df3 = (DEEP_SLEEP_PVT.groupby(['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)'])['Chip_Current[uAmp]']
                     .agg(['min','max']))
```

Sample data:

```
DEEP_SLEEP_PVT = (pd.DataFrame({'Chip_Current[uAmp]':[5,0,-1,2,3,2,1,-5,7,4.8],
                               'Device_ID':['FF_2646'] * 5 + ['TT_2438'] * 5,
                               'Temp(deg)':[-20]*3 + [25] * 2 + [-20]*3 + [25] * 2})
                    .set_index(['Device_ID','Temp(deg)']))
    
print (DEEP_SLEEP_PVT)
                     Chip_Current[uAmp]
Device_ID Temp(deg)                    
FF_2646   -20                       5.0
          -20                       0.0
          -20                      -1.0
           25                       2.0
           25                       3.0
TT_2438   -20                       2.0
          -20                       1.0
          -20                      -5.0
           25                       7.0
           25                       4.8
```

---

```
df1 = DEEP_SLEEP_PVT['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].agg(['min','max']).to_frame().T
print (df1)
                    min  max
Chip_Current[uAmp] -5.0  7.0
```

---

```
df2 = DEEP_SLEEP_PVT.groupby('Device_ID')['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].agg(['min','max'])
print (df2)
           min  max
Device_ID          
FF_2646   -1.0  5.0
TT_2438   -5.0  7.0
```

---

```
df3 = DEEP_SLEEP_PVT.groupby(['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)'])['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].agg(['min','max'])
print (df3)
                     min  max
Device_ID Temp(deg)          
FF_2646   -20       -1.0  5.0
           25        2.0  3.0
TT_2438   -20       -5.0  2.0
           25        4.8  7.0
```

Comment: It is working.I updated my question.I need spec max column after max column.

Comment: @HARITO - Not sure if understand, need `DEEP_SLEEP_PVT.agg(['min','max']).T` ?

Comment: Very helpful.Thank You

Comment: "to_frame().T" .May I know what is ".T" doing here

Comment: @HARITO - it is transpose [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)